# I keep on getting undefined in my parameters in my express + react website

Tags: reactjs, express

I am trying to create a an express + react app where the user is able to add, edit and delete items from a webProjects array. I have managed to get the add function to work and I have just about gotten the delete function to work however whenever I press on the delete button to delete the certain item from the webProjects displayed on the webpage the :id parameter keeps on coming out as undefined resulting in my api saying the project is not found and I dont know why that is. I believe it is on the client side where it doesnt work because I am able to get the function to work in postman.

```
Display.js

import React from 'react'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const Display = ({projectData, updateState}) => {

  const handleDelete = () => {

    console.log(projectData)

    fetch(`/api/${projectData.ID}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
     headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: projectData.ID
      }),
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        updateState(response)
      })
  
  
  }

  return (
       <div className="flex flex-wrap displayCard justify-center">
        {projectData.map((projectData, index) => (
            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key={projectData.ID}>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{projectData.TITLE}</Card.Title>
              <Card.Subtitle>{projectData.ID}</Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Text>
              Description: {projectData.DESCRIPTION}
              </Card.Text>
              <Card.Text>
                  URL: {projectData.URL}
              </Card.Text>
               <Card.Link ><Button>edit</Button></Card.Link>
              <Card.Link ><Button onClick={() => handleDelete()}>Delete</Button></Card.Link>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        ))}
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default Display

server.js

let webProjects = [
  {
    ID: uuidv4(),
    TITLE: "React Game",
    DESCRIPTION: "Tic tac toe game created using Create React App",
    URL: "http://someURL/myapp/game/",
  },
  {
    ID: uuidv4(),
    TITLE: "Online Store",
    DESCRIPTION: "Online store created with HTML, CSS and Javascript.",
    URL: "http://someURL2/shop/index",
  },
  {
    ID: uuidv4(),
    TITLE: "Online Game",
    DESCRIPTION: "Online game created with Python.",
    URL: "http://someURL3/shop2/index",
  },
];

app.delete("/api/:id", (req, res) => {
  const projectId = req.params.id;
    const projectIndex = webProjects.findIndex(project => project.ID === projectId);

    console.log(projectId)
    console.log(projectIndex)

    if (projectIndex === -1) {
        return res.status(404).send("Project not found");
    }

    webProjects.splice(projectIndex,1);
  //res.send(`The item was successfully deleted`)
    res.send(webProjects);

})
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mre] - you should be able to figure out whether the problem is on the client or server, at least.

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes that you suggested

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did wrong.

In the server.js file. Right at the end of the delete endpoint

```
 res.send(webProjects);
```

was meant to be

```
    res.json({webProjects});
```

And then on the frontend the function needed to change a bit in Display.js.

From:

```
const handleDelete = () => {

    console.log(projectData)

    fetch(`/api/${projectData.ID}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
     headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: projectData.ID
      }),
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        updateState(response)
      })


  }
```

To:

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {

    console.log(id)

    fetch(`/api/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
  })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        updateState(response)
      })
  
 
  }
```

And the final change was also in the Display.js file but it was how I called the function in the delete button.

Instead of:

```
<Button onClick={() => handleDelete()}>Delete</Button>
```

It should've been

```
<Button onClick={() => handleDelete(projectData.ID)}>Delete</Button>
```